# How to share folders that are on a partition on a secondary hard drive?

Tags: networking, partitioning, mount, directory, sharing

Here's my situation. I have a desktop computer with 2 hard drives in it. Hard drive 1 has windows installed on it and pretty much has nothing to do with this, I think.

Hard drive 2 has a partition with media files(music, movies, etc.), AND a partition that Ubuntu is installed on.

When running ubuntu, I can make folders on the media partition of hard drive 2 visible to other ubuntu computers on the network but when I try to access them from my laptop, which is also running ubuntu, I get prompted for a username and password, which ends in access denied when I enter my credentials.

I hope some one can help me and I hope I've been clear about by problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Link to filesystem**

One way would be to make a link to the filesystem, which should be in /media/directoryName.
Maybe you got to switch the 'write-bit' of the directory on. This usually should work.

```
A problem could be, if you can't make a link to the filesystem, read
```

`$ man ln`

That works when I use it.

Or try

`$ sudo mount partitionName /home/yourUserName/folder`